# Decoding GWT RequestFactory payload without Request from out-of-bound message

Tags: gwt, comet, requestfactory, atmosphere

We're using GWT Atmosphere to send strings from the server to the client and it works quite well.

However, we would like to send whole entities from the server to the client, serialized by the GWT RequestFactory. Without the need for a request by the client!

So I tried working with `SimpleRequestProcessor#createOobMessage(domainObject)` and sending that payload to the client. Computing the payload works.

I would then decode that message using `AutoBeanCodex#decode` and read the `domainObject` as the correct `EntityProxy` from the invocation list of the `ResponseMessage` - however when I do so, it requires some sort of `serverId` being set to proceed in `AbstractRequestFactory#getId` (around line 260: `assert serverId != null : "serverId"`)

Any advice on how I can decode a Proxy payload without a request being sent by the client?

#### Update

The use case for this question is chat-like communication. The client doesn't request the messages from the server but instead will be notified of new messages. And we'd like to include the messages and info on who's sent the message in the notification payload. Since we're using RequestFactory in our project anyway, we want to take advantage of having set up all the Proxy wiring and now simply push the relevant object graph to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to serialize RF messages and send them just as entities? RequestFactory is much more than justa way to send data over the wire - it has at least three different kinds of messages that can be sent from the client to the server: create instances, call setters, and invoke service methods. Based on what happens on the server, not only can data be returned to the client, but messages about what changes were made and if those setters made changes that are not valid under the JSR303 rules.

Are you trying for a simpler, interface way of describing, sending, and receiving entities? Or do you actually want the RF wiring on both client and server so you can batch requests, refer to EntityProxyId instances and have the client only send diffs?

If you just want simpler object declarations, try just using `AutoBean`s and the `AutoBeadCodex` you have already looked at - you'll be able to create and marshal instances on both client and server easily, and you can pass them as strings over atmosphere's transports.

If you actually want RequestFactory, but running over something other than AJAX, there are other options. Rather than sending/receiving strings through Atmosphere (which I believe is intended to provide push support for RPC calls), consider using that underlying push layer to implment a new request transport in RequestFactory.

`com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestTransport` can be implemented (see `com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.gwt.client.DefaultRequestTransport` for the default AJAX version) to use any communication mechanism you would like - and to build the server, take a look at `com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet` for what actually must be done to push messages through the Locator, ServiceLocators, etc.

If you really want to use Atmosphere and RF, then consider building a `RequestTransport` that wraps a simple Atmosphere interface to call to the server with the string - the cometd/websocket calls will already be taken care of for you, and you'll just have to translate the string message into invocations (again, see how RequestFactoryServlet does it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your deep explanation of the various ways of implementing RF. However, in this specific use case, we don't want to take advantage of the RF intelligence but rather use it as a serialization mechanism which (solely looking at the server) doesn't seem to be a problem.
But the client seems to require you to prepare the request for some reason. I am looking for the API bit that would just decode a message sent by the server, since we do not want to request the data but will just get it through comet without prior knowledge.

Comment: If you're only looking for a serialization mechanism, then use `AutoBean`s, not RF. IMO, RF with server-push would actually only be useful for sending entity diffs from the server to the client (as opposed to client-to-server in "traditional" RF).

Comment: Hi Thomas, that is exactly what I am looking for: an AutoBean implementation to decode an AutoBean encoded by the server. No matter if RF is the right choice for that or not. AutoBeanCodex#decode just expects some sort of serverId deeper in the code and I cannot find a way to circumvent that. Any advice?

Comment: AutoBeanCodex#decode only requires a factory (to get the classes that might be sent over the wire), the class you will return (to get the root class), and the payload itself. I use AutoBeans regularly to map directly to json (and xml, but that is more work) created by existing services that don't pass along any server id. The only properties that AutoBeans require are the ones in your interface, so make sure you aren't extending other interfaces like EntityProxy.

Comment: Thanks, I though I could re-use my already defined EntityProxies and somehow get a factory reproducing these - is there any way to do that? I would appreciate that since it would make things really easy.

Comment: I'm not sure you can have your cake and eat it too: not using RequestFactory to make things simple, but still getting the copying magic of RequestFactory. One way might be to look at bean-copying libraries that exist for the jvm already, explain to them to only copy the properties entity->autobean if the autobean has getters for them. And just remove the `extends EntityProxy` from your existing code.